# Search/Filter custom Widgets for QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

How can I search/filter custom widgets in the QListWidget?

For example, I have a custom form widget,

```
class MetadataForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(MetadataForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MetaInfo()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.data = data
        self.keywords = data['keywords']

        self.ui.pkg_name.setText(self.data['name'])
        self.ui.pkg_version.setText(self.data['version'])
        self.ui.pkg_desc.setText(self.data['desc'])
        self.ui.pkg_author_lbl.setText(self.data['author'])
        self.ui.pkg_pubdate_lbl.setText(self.data['pub_date'])

        self.ui.install_btn.clicked.connect(self.install_pkg)

    def install_pkg(self):
        print('hello from {}'.format(self.data['name']))
```

I can add these to my `MainWindow`

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
        self.ui = Ui_Main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.set_catalog_data()

    def set_catalog_data(self):
        for item in self.data:
            # print(item)
            metadata = MetadataForm(item)
            print(metadata.keywords)
            lst_item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            self.ui.catalog_list_wid.insertItem(
                self.ui.catalog_list_wid.count(),
                lst_item
            )
            self.ui.catalog_list_wid.setItemWidget(lst_item, metadata)
            lst_item.setSizeHint(metadata.sizeHint())
```

In my `MainWindow` my UI has a QLineEdit, named `self.ui.search_box`, how can I filter my custom `QListWidgetItem` based the keywords attribute of my Metadata class?

Some simple testing data:

```
test_data = [
    {
        'name': 'Foo Model',
        'version': 'v1.0.0.1',
        'desc': lorem.paragraph(),
        'author': 'Jane Doe',
        'pub_date': '10/14/2018',
        'keywords': ['foo']
    },
    {
        'name': 'Bar Model',
        'version': 'v1.0.0.1',
        'desc': lorem.paragraph(),
        'author': 'Jon Smith',
        'pub_date': '11/2/2018',
        'keywords': ['bar']
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to iterate over the rows and get keyword using the item () method to get the QListWidgetItem and then itemWidget to get the widget, using widget you get keywords and apply the filter, if you meet the filter it becomes visible otherwise you must hide

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
        self.ui = Ui_Main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.search_box.textChanged.connect(self.on_textChanged)
        self.set_catalog_data()

    def set_catalog_data(self):
        for item in self.data:
            # print(item)
            metadata = MetadataForm(item)
            lst_item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            self.ui.catalog_list_wid.insertItem(
                self.ui.catalog_list_wid.count(),
                lst_item
            )
            self.ui.catalog_list_wid.setItemWidget(lst_item, metadata)
            lst_item.setSizeHint(metadata.sizeHint())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_textChanged(self, text):
        for row in range(self.ui.catalog_list_wid.count()):
            it = self.ui.catalog_list_wid.item(row)
            widget = self.ui.catalog_list_wid.itemWidget(it)
            if text: 
                it.setHidden(not self.filter(text, widget.keywords))
            else:
                it.setHidden(False)

    def filter(self, text, keywords):
        # foo filter
        # in the example the text must be in keywords
        return text in keywords
```